# zklib: zk.getAttendance() returns False

Tags: python, bioinformatics

I have **Two ZkTeco** Attendance Machines. Both are version **6.60**.
One was implemented in **2013** and other in **2015**.
The following code is working for both.

```
zk = zklib.ZKLib(host, port)
res = zk.connect()
if res:
      zk.enableDevice()
```

But below code only works for new machine (2015).

```
zk.getAttendance()
```

**The old machine(2013) returns False**. But it has content are used in existing windows software.

Answer (score 0):

Two device set variations are there in terms of ZkTeco SDK. Communication protocol from "Black&White" device SDK to TFT Device SDK is slightly upgraded. It looks like your zklib is working on TFT protocol. May be your older devices is working on Black&White device SDK. Check your vendor, if you can get the firmware of the newer device and upgrade your older device with the new firmware. Or check the ZKLIB developer to upgrade the protocol.